# What's the best way to search GitHub?

Tags: search, tags, github, tagging

The search feature on the site seems pretty awful.

Are there any external sites that do a better job of categorizing projects with tags, etc?

Or maybe I'm just not using GitHub correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried a Google search with `site:github.com` included in the query?

Comment: Returns too many extraneous results - problem is both the Google search and the Github search look within the code files.

Comment: Never mind - found it - by searching "Repositories" instead of Code, I get what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this, but I understand that very often Google does a better job of searching a website than the site's own search tools. Have you tried that?

Go to their [advanced search](http://www.google.com/advanced_search) page and fill out github.com in the "Only return results from this site or domain" slot.

Answer (score 1):

[hubscovery.com](http://hubscovery.com) is much better.

GitHub's search functionality is terrible. I'm all for everyone having their own opinion, but for such a well-done site in nearly every other way, there is no excuse for lacking a basic sort option. It is to their service.

EDIT: Hubscovery is dead! Long live GitHub search!

Comment: the above link is broken (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻  I guess github got their act together and implemented a better search.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub indexes a tremendous amount of data ([50+ million projects](https://github.com/about)). Taking a moment to understand their [search syntax](https://help.github.com/articles/search-syntax/) should help you narrow your search.